# Eclipse IDE crashes after certain number of runs but runs fine with VALGRIND profiler

Tags: valgrind, omnet++

When I run a code in OMNeT++ (eclipse based IDE), the simulation crashes after certain number of events. So to check for a memory leak, I used VALGRIND. When I run the code using this valgrind profiler, my simulation runs perfectly fine. I don't know the reason for this peculiar behavior. Can someone explain the reason behind this ?

Answer (score 0):

Probably a 'heisenbug". I.e. an issue that changes its behavior if you try to examine it. It could be an uninitialized variable or other obscure bug that did not surface if the program starts with a different memory layout (i.e. under valgrind).

I would still look into the valgring logs, even if the crash does not occur as the logs may cotain some hints.